# Why does my Loop no work properly?

Tags: c++

I have this code below that allows the user to amend file. The problem I have is that when I run through it once it works. But let say I want to open the txt file again it doesn't open.

```
string line, line2;
string data, moduleID, input;
int Choice;
ifstream samsFile("SAMS.txt");
fstream registeredModule("210CTStudentModule.txt");

if(! samsFile){
    cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    return 0;
}
do{
    cout<<"HELLO AND WELCOME!!!"<<endl;
    cout<<"what do you want to do?"<<endl;
    cout<<"1: Check Registered Students"<<endl;
    cout<<"2: Register Student To Module"<<endl;
    cout<<"3: Open Registered Module File"<<endl;
    cout<<"4: Logout"<< endl;
    cin>>Choice;
    if(Choice==1){
            while(getline(samsFile,line)){
                cout<<line<<endl;
            }
    }else if(Choice==2){
            vector<string>example;
            while(getline(samsFile,data)){
                example.push_back(data);
            }
            cout<<"What Module Do You Want To Add?: "<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin>>moduleID;
            vector<string>moduleCode;
            for(unsigned int j=0;j<example.size();j++){
                moduleCode.push_back(moduleID);
            }
            for(unsigned int k=0;k<moduleCode.size();k++){
                registeredModule<<moduleCode[k]<<" "<<example[k]<<"\n";
            }
    }else if(Choice==3){
        while(getline(registeredModule,line2)){
            cout<<line2<<endl;
        }
    }
}while(Choice!=4);
cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
return 0;
```

Anyone has any idea why this is so?

Comment: Where do you open again?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. The code you show here opens the file exactly once

Comment: And which file - there are 2 files being openned here

Comment: I'm guessing that your problem is that, in the second time through the loop, you are located at the end of the file and thus can not read it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes i see i included the fstream in the do while loop and it works now thanks. i learnt c++ a while back but haven't practice it for a while. thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited piece of your code. Declare "samsFile" inside ***while loop*** (as Basya Perlman said).

```
do{
ifstream samsFile("SAMS.txt");
cout<<"HELLO AND WELCOME!!!"<<endl;
cout<<"what do you want to do?"<<endl;
cout<<"1: Check Registered Students"<<endl;
cout<<"2: Register Student To Module"<<endl;
cout<<"3: Open Registered Module File"<<endl;
cout<<"4: Logout"<< endl;
cin>>Choice;
if(Choice == 1){
        while(getline(samsFile,line)){
            cout<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
}while(Choice!=4);
cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
```

It works for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the file each time through the loop, put the initialization of the stream inside the loop.  The file will be closed when you leave the scope, and opened when you enter it.

If you don't mind having it open all the time, and the problem is that you are at the end of the file the second time through the loop, you can use seekg each time through the loop to reposition yourself at the beginning of the file.